# Proof $C$= {$(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x+y=b $} is convex

Tags: convex-analysis, convex-optimization

In an optimization problem, I have constraints of the form $x+y=b$.
In order to prove that the solution is unique, I proved that the criterion is strictly convex and now I need to show that the set of constraints :

> $C$= {$(x, y) \in \mathbb{R}^2 | x+y=b $} is convex.

I wanted to go by the definition and prove  that $z=tx+(1-t)y$  $\in C$ for $ t ∈ [0,1]$ but I don't see how I can get to the result ?

Thank you

Comment: It is quite immediate from the definition. What have you tried?

Comment: In order to show that $z∈C$ I must show that $z=b$. To do that, do I have to define $z$ and $z'$ with $z=tx+(1-t)x'$ and $z'=ty+(1-t)y'$ and show that $z+z'=b$ ?

Comment: That's not the definition of a convex set. You /start/ with two arbitrary points in $C$. Then show that their convex combination is in $C$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is what you have to show:

Suppose $(x_1,y_1)\in C$, that is$$x_1 + y_1 = b$$

and $(x_2,y_2)\in C$,
$$x_2+y_2=b$$

Show that $(\lambda x_1 +(1-\lambda )x_2,\lambda y_1 +(1-\lambda) y_2) \in C$, that is

$$(\lambda x_1+(1-\lambda)x_2)+(\lambda y_1+(1-\lambda)y_2)=b$$

where $\lambda \in [0,1]$.